# Why was Dr. Logan chosen by John Kramer?

Tags: plot-explanation, saw, jigsaw

In this latest [*Jigsaw 2017*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jigsaw_(2017_film)) movie, it turns out that Dr. Logan was kidnapped and saved by John Kramer ten years ago before the main plot starts.

It is a known fact that John Kramer does not kidnap innocent people so why Dr. Logan was kidnapped and put in Saw games?

It is not explained in this movie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dr. Logan Nelson was the person who mislabeled John Kramer's cancer X-Rays. Due to this, the condition of John was not diagnosed and when it did, it was too late. So, Dr. Logan was not innocent at all.

However, John showed him mercy and saved him when Dr. Logan was severely injured.

From [Hollywood Reporter](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/heat-vision/jigsaw-twist-ending-is-an-existential-experience-1052676)

> Apparently, Logan was once a hospital orderly who accidentally mislabeled John's medical X-rays, thereby preventing him from getting timely treatment for his fatal brain tumor.

From [this source](http://comicbook.com/movies/2017/10/28/jigsaw-ending-spoilers-saw-movie-connections/)

> Nelson (a former Iraq War medic turned doctor) was **actually the man responsible for first mislabeling John Kramer's cancer X-Rays, which led to Kramer's condition not being diagnosed until it was too late.** Kramer abducted Nelson and made him a player in his very first prototype game; however, when Nelson was severely injured, Kramer decided to show him mercy (more on that later). As a man dealing with PTSD form his time as a POW, Nelson was a prime candidate to fall under sway of Kramer's brainwashing.

Comment: thanks. i thought mislabeling part was a lie that was used to deceive other detective into confession.

Comment: Yeah. Saw movies have overly convoluted plots, so I understand the confusion.